# React- Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to store a user using redux so that I can access it in my Nav bar and display the user's name after he has logged in. I have created a store and a userSlice however, I keep getting the error that: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Due to this reason my redux is unable to store the user. I still get the initial values thaat I set in my redux store.

It will be of great help if assistance can be offered by helping my edit my code for better undertanding for I have tried some solutions but I am unable to implementthe solution correctly.

**index.js:**

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import userReducer from "./features/user";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
  },
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**user.js:**

```
export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    value: { name: "", id: 0, email: "", loginId: "" },
  },
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { login } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

**login_component.js:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { login } from "../features/user";

function Login() {
  const [LoginID, setLoginID] = useState("");
  const [Password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [LoginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [logID, setLogID] = useState("");
  const [id, setId] = useState("");

  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const login = (event) => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/login", {
        LoginID: LoginID,
        Password: Password,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.message) {
          setLoginStatus(response.data.message);
        } else {
          setLoginStatus(response.data.result[0].UserFullName);
          setEmail(response.data.result[0].UserEmailID);
          setLogID(response.data.result[0].LoginID);
          setId(response.data.result[0].UserID);
        }
      });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(
      login({
        name: { LoginStatus },
        id: { id },
        email: { email },
        loginId: { logID },
      })
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8000/login").then((response) => {
      if (response.data.loggedIn === true) {
        setLoginStatus(response.data.user[0].UserFullName);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="auth-wrapper">
        <div className="auth-inner">
          <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
            <h3>Log In</h3>

            <div className="form-group ">
              <label>Login ID</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Login ID"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setLoginID(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Password"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setPassword(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>

            <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block" onClick={login}>
              Login
            </button>
          </form>
          <h1>{LoginStatus}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

**nav_component.js:**

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import user from "../features/user";

function Nav(props) {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.value);
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light fixed-top">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <Link to={"/"} class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">
            Home
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <Link to={"/register"} class="nav-link">
            Register
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <Link to={"/login"} class="nav-link">
            Login
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <Link
            to={"/admin"}
            class="nav-link"
            //tabindex="-1"
            //aria-disabled="true"
          >
            Admin
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="username">
        <li>Welcome {user.id}</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Nav;
```

Comment: If you need async actions you can use redux-thunk

Comment: Yes I have read about that but am unable to implement it correctly. If you could help me do that, that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically I changed my approach a little bit.
Instead of using configureStore from @reduxjstoolkit, I used createStore from redux.

Furthermore, I made my login funtion in login_component to be an async-awit function so that I can get an object. I also useed action creators to perform the login action in the User slice.